# Unable to resolve host in AKS -dial tcp: lookup url.com on xxxxx:53: no such host

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, dns, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am running my application on AKS (private sub-net)

In my pod I am trying to access a github API and it fails with Post

> "https://GHESurl.com/api/v3/repos/org/myrepo/actions/runners/registration-token":
> POST
> https://GHESurl.com/api/v3/repos/org/myrepo/actions/runners/registration-token
> giving up after 5 attempt(s): Post
> "https://GHESurl.com/api/v3/repos/org/myrepo/actions/runners/registration-token":
> dial tcp: lookup GHESurl.com on 10.x.x.x:53: no such host"}

The same curl works fine when attempted form a jump-host in Azure (/etc/host is updated to resolve the domain).